# How to use one html to render different content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have several a link in 'a' HTML. I expect the page to open in a new window when I click each link and these new windows are using the 'b' HTML. I would like to use 'b' HTML renders different content via different URL, such as /get_node or /get_vue etc. But 'b' HTML has only one URL.

If I pass get parameters to that URL like http://localhost:8000/xxxx.html?show=something,how to make AngularJs can receive this parameters?

For instance, here is 'a' HTML code.

```
<ul class='list-wrapper'>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">Javascript</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">Node.js</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">Angular</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">Vue</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">CSS/SASS</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">NPM</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX">Gulp</a></li>
  <li class='getback'><i class="fas fa-times"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Here is 'b' HTML code, `http://XXXXXXXXXXXX.html`. 
URL get by angularjs via $http.get.

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('index',($scope,$http)=>{
    $http.get('/get_js',then((res)=>{
      $scope.js = res.data;
    },()=>{
      alert('database error');
    })
  })
```

Could anyone tell me how can I do that? Can I put several URLs in $http.get to solve it?

Thank you very much!!

PS: I am using an express server to host the content.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve here `I would like to use 'b' HTML renders different content, but 'b' HTML has only one URL` You want to get one URL but you want it to return different webpage/content? If yes then you need different URL, or pass get parameters to that URL like `http://localhost:8083/cat.html?show=something` In that case your express server must serve different content depending on those parameters

Comment: Yes, could you tell me how to make the AngularJs receive the several passing get parameters?

Comment: @Sylvia Are you familiar with the [angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router)?

Comment: @farlee2121 yes